# Stilts.js Unable to connect to websocket server with secure true

Tags: javascript, security, ssl, stomp, torquebox

I am having issues with subscribing to my websocket server when I turn the secure option to true. I ran an SSL validator to make sure it was set up properly and everything passed. Also to be safe, I also checked with my hosting provider so I dont believe that is the issue. And also, everything does work when secure is set to false.

The WSS is running on port 8676, and I did make sure that port is open.

I am using the Stomp Javascript library. I downloaded the latest version from their github master branch (https://github.com/projectodd/stilts/blob/master/stomp-client-js/src/main/javascript/stomp.js).

I keep getting this error inside the `_transmit()` function: `can't call transmit on undefined`

It seems to not be setting the `_transport` property inside of `_buildConnector()` function. I added some console.logs and it always goes to the `else` statement in this function.

Any ideas on a fix? Or am I just missing something?

This is how I am initializing my connection:

`client = new Stomp.Client('my.ip.address', 8676, true);`

Here is where I am logging some of the functions:

`Stomp.Client = function(host, port, secure) {
    console.log('host param: ' + host);
    console.log('port param: ' + port);
    console.log('secure param: ' + secure);
    this._host   = host   || Stomp.DEFAULT_HOST;
    this._port   = port   || Stomp.DEFAULT_PORT || 8675;
    this._secure = secure || Stomp.DEFAULT_SECURE_FLAG || false;
    console.log('this._host: ' + this._host);
    console.log('this._port: ' + this._port);
    console.log('this._secure: ' + this._secure);
}`

**Output:**

`host param: my.ip.address
port param: 8676
secure param: true
this._host: my.ip.address
this._port: 8676
this._secure: true`

`_buildConnector: function(transports, i) {
    console.log('INSIDE _buildConnector()');
    var callback = this._connectCallback;
    var client = this;
    if ( i < transports.length ) {
      console.log('IF!!!');
      return function() {
        var fallback = client._buildConnector( transports, i+1, callback );
        try {
          console.log('_buildConnector::IF::TRY');
          transports[i].connect( function() {
            client._transport = transports[i];
            callback();
          }, fallback );
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('_buildConnector::IF::CATCH');
          fallback();
        }
      };
    } else {
      console.log('_buildConnector::ELSE');
      return client.connectionFailed.bind(this);
    }
  }`

**Output:**

`INSIDE _buildConnector()
IF!!!
INSIDE _buildConnector()
IF!!!
_buildConnector::IF::TRY
INSIDE _buildConnector()
_buildConnector::ELSE
_buildConnector::IF::TRY`

`connectionFailed: function() {
    console.log('INSIDE connectionFailed()');
    if (this._errorCallback)
    {
      console.log('connectionFailed::IF');
      console.log('this._errorCallback');
      console.log(this._errorCallback);
      console.log('arguments');
      console.log(arguments);
      this._errorCallback.apply(this._errorCallback, arguments);
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('connectionFailed::ELSE');
      console.log('unable to connect :(');
      Stomp.logger.log( "unable to connect" );
    }
  }`

**Output:**
`No output..`

Comment: also want to note that the web app server and the websocket server are on 2 different machines. Not sure if that is part of the problem.

Comment: I tried moving the websocket server to the same machine as the web app, still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this node.js tool called `wscat` which can be used to send messages to a websocket server (http://einaros.github.io/ws/).

When entering the command using the external address:
`wscat -c wss://my.ip.address:8676`

I kept getting the following error: `error: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames`

But when I changed it to my domain name:
`wscat -c wss://mydomain.com:8676`

I was given this message: `connected (press CTRL+C to quit)`

Which led me to:

I am setting the host value in Javascript as the external ip address of the server where STOMP lives. But the SSL cert is configured for a domain name. This led me to think that I should use `mydomain.com` instead of `my.ip.address` for the host parameter in `new Stomp.Client`. But this is resulting in the following error in the Torquebox log file:

`NoSuchHostException: No such host: mydomain.com`

So then in the `torquebox.yml` file the host property needed to be configured to `mydomain.com` as well.

So the conclusion is: You need to use the domain name that was registered to the SSL cert when trying to connect to your websocket server, not the external ip address. huzzah!

Credit to:  @bobmcwhirter who helped lead me to this solution here: https://github.com/projectodd/stilts/issues/20